# Using Mathematica how can I simulate the MD5 or SHA encryption of a userid and password performed by htpasswd on Apache?

Tags: webservices, hashing, authentication

`htpasswd` hashes a user's password using the userid. Thus [this generator](http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/) takes both userid and password as inputs and then it outputs a line for inclusion in the `.htpasswd` file. For example using the inputs "test" (userid) and "hello" (password), I got `test:$apr1$ftcMHGnd$ZBAuErXOcG9n4PH9vGLFe/`, ready for pasting into `.htpasswd`.

How can I simulate this using Mathematica?

The best I've got at the moment is

```
Hash["a-string-here", "MD5"] ,
```

which takes only a single input and outputs in decimal.

Comment: According to [this](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/misc/password_encryptions.html), you would need to use "an Apache-specific algorithm using an iterated (1,000 times) MD5 digest of various combinations of a random 32-bit salt and the password. See the APR source file apr_md5.c for the details of the algorithm."

Comment: You can run the htpasswd command line tool from within Mathematica and get the encrypted passwords that way, if this is of interest.

Comment: The hash doesn't have to be the same as one produced by `htpasswd`, just so long as it validates. Can this not be done with `Hash` in Mathematica, so long as one can pass it the right input that combines userid and password?

Comment: Their `SHA` scheme is much easier to generate, e.g. ``StringJoin[userid, "{SHA}", Developer`EncodeBase64[FromCharacterCode[IntegerDigits[Hash[password, "SHA"], 256]]]]``

Comment: Thanks, @ilian . SHA will do me fine. I will edit the question to say MD5 or SHA and will then accept your answer.

Comment: Comments turned into an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/misc/password_encryptions.html), the MD5 scheme uses "an Apache-specific algorithm using an iterated (1,000 times) MD5 digest of various combinations of a random 32-bit salt and the password. See the APR source file [apr_md5.c](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/apr/apr/trunk/crypto/apr_md5.c?view=markup) for the details of the algorithm."

While that could in principle be implemented, it's much easier to generate the SHA1-digest form:

```
htpasswdsha[userid_?StringQ, password_?StringQ] := StringJoin[userid, ":{SHA}", 
  Developer`EncodeBase64[FromCharacterCode[IntegerDigits[Hash[password, "SHA"], 256, 20]]]]
```

For example,

```
htpasswdsha["myName", "myPassword"]

(* "myName:{SHA}VBPuJHI7uixaa6LQGWx4s+5GKNE=" *)
```

Instead of `` Developer`EncodeBase64 `` one could use the documented `ExportString[str, "Base64"]` but that seems to add an extra newline (`"\n"`) character at the end.

The same function can be written in a much simpler way with the recently released version 11.3.0, using only [`BaseEncode`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BaseEncode.html) and [`Hash`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hash.html):

```
htpasswdsha[userid_?StringQ, password_?StringQ] := 
  StringJoin[userid, ":{SHA}", BaseEncode[Hash[password, "SHA", "ByteArray"]]]
```